# Autolayout in Interface Builder alter layout based on outer view width/height

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a horizontal layout of three items (views) that are equal width and equal horizontal spacing so they grow in width as the view expands in width.

But when the view grows in height and shrinks in width I want those items to be placed one above the other (**see diagram**).

Using a combination of auto layout constraints, prioritizing certain ones etc can this be achieved? Or will I have to create two different views with the two different layouts and load the correct one in at the correct time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created two different views with one view controller so that I could share the outlets.

I then switch between these two views when I need to (on rotation).